# Clickable layout with inner views behavior issue

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am testing creating a compound view, so I started with a Linear Layout containing a ImageView and a TextView. These LinearLayout will represent a view similar to a partial list, and I made it clickable. The inner Views of the layout have selectors as its color (TextView) and image (ImageView). In the API 19 (KitKat), the click behavior is ok (screenshot 1) but on API 15 and API 10 (screenshot 2), the click didn't changed the selector state.

The code of each 'list item' is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_login"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/signin_signup_icon_facebook" />

    <TextView
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Facebook"
        android:textColor="@color/option_text_color" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

[image: API 19]

[image: API 15]

EDIT: I used the touch listener approach. If someday I find a best solution (without Java code), I edit here. My approach, based on the answers (adding the a View.OnTouchListener to the LinearLayouts):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) view;
    boolean pressed;
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) pressed = true;
    else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) pressed = false;
    else return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
        container.getChildAt(i).setPressed(pressed);
    }

    return false;
}
```

In an old 2.3 Android the code runs a bit slowly but works too.

Comment: Please post your adapter file code

Comment: It isn't a list. It's a LinearLayout with inner LinearLayouts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried in different APIs and have the same problem with you. I think the old API may not have this feature which allows inner view's appearance to respond to it's parent view's click method.

You can change the inner view's appearance in your code by using touchListenr or you can try not using LinearLayout but just a TextView with a picture in it , use `android:drawableLeft`, then you can change both image and text and background at the same time.

EDIT:
using onTouchListener like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    imageView.setPressed(true);
    textView.setPressed(true);
}
else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    imageView.setPressed(false);
    textView.setPressed(false);
}
return false;
}
```

Hope it mey help you.

Comment: The reason that I didn't used a compound drawable is that, if I used wrap_content in TextView, the background didn't filled all the width, and, if I use match_parent, the image always aligned the left side of the screen...

Comment: Yes…it has that problem. Just make it in Java code, anaway, it's not so much complex. ps. if you find a solution without Java please tell me ^_^ @Rafael

Answer (score 1):

you should not use 4 layouts for same kind of layout it, better approach would be use listview.But this can also be solved like this:

set ontouchlistner for linear layout

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
//change image view (white image) and text color(white) and linear layout background color(Red) here
  break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
//change image view (red image) and text color(red) and linear layout background color(white) here
  break;
```

this will solve your problem, and surely it will work like charm or you can use linear layout to work like button and set selector for layout like this:
[Making a LinearLayout act like an Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546514/making-a-linearlayout-act-like-an-button)

Comment: The reason to use the LinearLayouts is that the list may not scroll. And the recommendation for no scrollable lists is to use LinearLayout, isn't it?

Comment: hmm! ok! does my solution helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Try Some like that:

Your Xml file

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLaout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_login"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iamge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/signin_signup_icon_facebook" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Facebook"
        android:textColor="@color/option_text_color" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

simply Which click change the background of linear Layout Color
and also change the background on image view and also chnage the color of text view. and others remain same.

Check that link use like that selector totatly [Android LinearLayout Selector background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273510/android-linearlayout-selector-background-color)

Comment: Also post your java file

Comment: There's no Java code. I only inflated from XML in a Fragment