# Adding Ripple Effect to RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add Ripple Effect to RecyclerView's item. I had a look online, but could not find what I need. I assume it has to be a custom effect. I have tried android:background attribute to the RecyclerView itself and set it to "?android:selectableItemBackground" but it did not work.:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"/>
```

This is the RecyclerView that I am trying to add the effect to:

[image]

Comment: I'm reopening this as not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961147/touch-feedback-with-recyclerview-and-cardview). Although the solutions may be similar, there are certain aspects of a having a `CardView` in that question than do not pertain to this more general question.

Comment: @Suragch Thank you for noticing the difference :)

Answer (score 304, accepted):

I figured out. The only thing that I had to do is to add this attribute:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

to the root element of the layout that my RecyclerView adapter inflates like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    tools:background="@drawable/bg_gradient">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/shoppingListItem"
        android:hint="@string/enter_item_hint"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/shopping_list_item_checkbox_label"
        android:id="@+id/shoppingListCheckBox"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:checked="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image]

If you are still not able to see ripple effect, add these lines also to the root element of the layout.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: What if the root element is CardView?

Comment: @SpiderMan You should write your code inside a Relative or a Linear Layout and then place it inside the Card Layout.

Comment: @pronoobsanved, this helped me! For those who are still facing the problem, CardView takes a single layout as a child. For that child, set clickable, focusable as true and background as ?attr/selectedableItemBackground

Comment: glad I could help.

Comment: @NabinKhadka for a CardView set it as the foreground instead, i.e. `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: By using this solution, only ripple effect works. Custom background is not working.

Comment: I guess, it does not. I have not tested it with a custom background

Comment: I had to add the option `android:clickable="true"` also to make this work

Comment: How to use this if I want a custom background ??

Comment: @mrid This should help http://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-material-design-for-ripple-effect-on-click/

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev Hey I try out this but its not working.

Answer (score 93):

As already answered, the simplest solution is to just add one of the following as your `RecyclerView` row's background:

- `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`
- `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`

However if you are experiencing [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969769/selectableitembackground-crashing-app) with this method or if you want finer control over the colors, then you can do the following.

## Custom Ripple Effect

This answer is starting with [this simple Android RecyclerView example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584425/3681880). It will look like the following image.

[image: Ripple effect example GIF]

## Add selector for pre API 21 devices

Before API 21 (Android 5.0 Lollipop), clicking a `RecyclerView` item just changed its background color (no ripple effect). That is what we are going to do, too. If you still have users with those devices, they are used to that behavior, so we aren't going to worry about them too much. (Of course, if you really want the ripple effect for them, too, you could use a [custom library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26604471/3681880).)

Right click your `res/drawable` folder and choose **New > Drawable resource file**. Call it `custom_ripple`. Click OK and paste in the following code.

*custom_ripple.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I used `colorAccent` as the highlight color for the pressed state because it was already available, but you can define whatever color you want.

## Add Ripple Effect for API 21+ devices

Right click your `res/drawable` folder and choose **New > Drawable resource file**. Call it `custom_ripple` again. Don't click OK, yet this time, though. From the **Available qualifiers** list choose **Version**, then click the **>>** button and write `21` for the **Platform API level**. Now click OK and paste in the following code.

*v21/custom_ripple.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorAccent">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</ripple>
```

Again, I used `colorAccent` for the ripple color because it was available, but you can use whatever color you want. The mask confines the ripple effect to just the row layout. The mask color apparently [doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556160/rippledrawable-mask-color-what-is-it-for) so I just used an opaque white.

## Set as the background

In your RecyclerView item's root layout, set the background to the custom ripple that we created.

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_ripple"
```

In the [example project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584425/3681880) that we started with, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_ripple"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAnimalName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

## Finished

That's it. You should be able to run your project now. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31853752/3681880) and [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvVkDb7DqCk) for help.

Comment: If you want to have a default background color just remove the 'android:id="@android:id/mask' line and then set the color of the drawable to whatever you want.

Answer (score 33):

I think there is one small detail that is missed.

If you still do not get the ripple effect after adding `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` try adding these following lines in the root of the layout.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

These will make sure that the view is clickable and will enable the ripple effect with the **background** attribute mentioned above

Answer (score 9):

add this lines in your adapter xml root view

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Answer (score 5):

### Using a Button Style

This has worked for me countlessly.

Add the Borderless Button Style to the root element of your layout.
There's no need for `focusable` or `clickable` attributes, the default styling encapsulates all that for you.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: @ededede You can use the min-height, max-height, width...XML attributes to tweak it to your taste.

Answer (score 4):

## A simple and custom approach is to set a view theme as outlined [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-missing-custom-ripple-effect-library-834521721b41#2f80).

*some_view.xml*

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:src="@drawable/up_arrow"
   android:theme="@style/SomeButtonTheme"/>
```

*some_style.xml*

```
<style name="SomeButtonTheme" >
   <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/someColor</item>
</style>
```

*Other custom implementations may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008609/add-ripple-effect-to-my-button-with-button-background-color/60893838).*