# Possible to show ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground on short touches?

Tags: android

When using the *selectableItemBackground* attribute for "touch ripple effects", it seems that normal touches are too fast for the "touch ripple" to appear. I have to touch a bit longer and everything works as it should. Is it possible to force this effect some how, even on short touches?

Answer (score 0):

I should suggest to you that create a custom ripple effect.

**Selector for Pre API 21**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**Ripple Effect for API 21+ Devices**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorAccent">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</ripple>
```

**For More:** [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931889/adding-ripple-effect-to-recyclerview-item)