# Same Ripple drawable(effect) appearing differently on ListView and RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, material-design, rippledrawable

I am implementing Android Material design Ripple effect by creating custom Ripple `Drawable` from `xml`.

Here id the code of  `ripple_effect_blue.xml`

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" >
    </item>
</ripple>
```

But my problem is that this same drawable creating the different effect(ripple) on `RecyclerView` and `ListView`.

Here are the screen shots of both views.
[image: List View Sample]

[image: Recycler View Sample]

I have already wasted plenty of time finding the cause of difference but no luck.

Comment: Check My Answer. here is your answer [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40008782/5967703)

Comment: Could you prepare a minimal working example of your issue and push it to github? Your case seems to be interesting, but it's hard to find the reason for the issue without the possibility to run the code.

Comment: ok, I will do this, currently, I am in middle of something once I finish this I will upload my source on git.