# Android ripple for button not working

Tags: android, ripple

The ripple effect I have given to the background of the button is not working.It just switches the color.The device version is 5.1.1.Please help me!!!

ripple.xml:

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/white"> <!-- ripple color -->

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/> <!-- normal color -->

</ripple>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in above xml. You may try to change ripple syntax by create 2 items with "@android:id/mask" and "@android:id/content" as it might be a bug related to a specified devices. Also if your project is supporting lower than 5.0, you may try Analyze APK to see if the apk was generates with the correct resource in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:text="New Button" />
```

But here you cant change ripple effect color

Comment: Why use "?attr/selectableItemBackground". Inspite of that we assign the @drawable/ripple

Comment: @jobin  "?attr/selectableItemBackground" to your view's foreground attribute if it already has a background along with android:clickable="true"

Comment: for more information check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008609/add-ripple-effect-to-my-button-with-button-background-color) add the "?attr/selectableItemBackground" to your view's foreground attribute if it already has a background along with android:clickable="true"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how to set the normal background color when using ripple tag.

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/white"> <!-- ripple color -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" /> <!-- normal color -->
      </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do is like this -

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#66ef5350"
    > <!-- ripple color -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#66ef5350" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ef5350" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        </shape>

    </item>

</ripple>
```

You can change the color as per your requirements.