# Button ripple effect spread to cover only alpha image OR avoid covering transparent spots

Tags: android, android-layout, button

What I have read previously

1. [Add ripple effect to my button with button background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008609/add-ripple-effect-to-my-button-with-button-background-color)
2. [Android ripple for button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014186/android-ripple-for-button-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. [Ripples on a shape with a transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445342/ripples-on-a-shape-with-a-transparent-background)
4. [Transparent background in ImageButton with ripple effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364534/transparent-background-in-imagebutton-with-ripple-effect)
5. [RippleDrawable - dev](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html)

What I need is to make custom ripple effect cover only alpha channel of my image OR avoid covering transparent spots.

My original botton

```
            <Button
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_round"
                android:foreground="@drawable/btn_ripple"/>
```

What I have tried from suggested with button
`android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless‌​"`
`android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless‌​"`. It did not quite work. In fact it ignores borders of my image and shape set in ripple whilst I need to constrain ripple spread shape to alpha channel.

As you already can see I have 3 options to combine

1. custom button shape
2. custom ripple
3. cutting-off alpha channel from suggested options

So I tried transforming `button` into `imageButton`

```
           <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_round"
                android:foreground="@drawable/btn_ripple"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

However I have tried all combinations of `src`, `background` and `foreground` for all 3 and did not succeed. Also tried adding 
`android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless‌​"`
`android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless‌​"` to ripple. That doesn't work either.

Reference this picture (that one does not have alpha but that is not the case)

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was plain to see:

in ripple.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@android:id/mask"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_enable" />
```

without `< shape >` inside

Answer (score 0):

Add a mask to the ripple effect. Only the alpha channel of the mask is used so it can be the same as your background image.

```
var rippleColorLst = android.content.res.ColorStateList.valueOf(
    android.graphics.Color.argb(255,50,150,255)
);
var ripple = new android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable(
    rippleColorLst,
    yourImageDrawableWithAlpha,
    yourImageDrawableWithAlpha   // the 3rd parameter is mask
); 
yourButtor.setBackground(ripple);
```

(Sorry for the JavaScript/NativeScript code, hope everyone can understand it.)