# Android - How to implement water ripple effect on button click?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation, ripple

so I am trying to implement something like a ripple water effect on an Android app where I can click only on a button and the ripple would affect everything that is currently displayed except the clicked button.

I don't really know how to start, any suggestions?

Comment: possible Duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008609/add-ripple-effect-to-my-button-with-button-background-color

Comment: Hope this will help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008609/add-ripple-effect-to-my-button-with-button-background-color

Comment: start from here https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background