# about background property in xml android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button, material-design

I use one button and i try to add two attrs in background property like add drawable xml and also want add ripple effect attrs `"?attr/selectableItemBackground"` Is it possible? My xml button code is here :-

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/btnRead"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:background="@drawable/readmcq"
         android:text="@string/readmcq"
         android:textAllCaps="false"
         android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
         android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Can i try like this `android:background="@drawable/readmcq" | "?attr/selectableItemBackground"` ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008609/add-ripple-effect-to-my-button-with-button-background-color

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `tagetSdk` greater than `20` Use this edited `Button`

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btnRead"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/readmcq"
    android:text="@string/readmcq"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

if you are using lesser than use this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRead"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/readmcq"
        android:text="@string/readmcq"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Let me know if it works. Happy coding :-)

Comment: When do we use android:background vs android:foreground?