# warp a view in android

Tags: java, android

i want to warp views in android ,

for example need to create wave on top of screen and any time can convert it to straight line

or

use a button in bottom navigation bar which create a wave on bottom navigation

please visit screenshots:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

Comment: need to create wave on top of screen and any time can convert it to straight line means?

Comment: when you click it shows in wave and then after noraml view like other menu?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008609/add-ripple-effect-to-my-button-with-button-background-color

Comment: @AD10 please visit screenshots, on scroll convert to a straight line

Comment: you can use shape drawable
https://android.jlelse.eu/android-shape-drawables-tutorial-17fbece6fef5

Comment: @AD10 i don't need ripple effect :)

Comment: @AmirHosseinMirzaei agha salam, shape haye sade nemikham, fekr mikonam yechi to mayehaye canvas html bashe :D :|

Comment: @Bahadori salam ehtemalan bayad khodeton custom view besazi va to onDraw nahve keshide shodan view ro moshakhas koni

Comment: @AmirHosseinMirzaei chetor mishe onjor custom view ei sakht?

Comment: @Bahadori dar had mobtadi mitoni tutorial hayi ke hasto bebini bad say koni bar asas ona chizi ke khodet mikhayo piyade koni

Answer (score 0):

This is new Design as per material IO. It is introduced in material design 2. You need to add anchor for using that type of view.

There are some changes which need to be noted.

- This is `AppBar` which is placed at bottom not `BottomNavigatioView`.
- It can be used for multi-purpose, so chose your use wisely.
- You can modify design as your need.

Following code can be used to achieve that functionality.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- Other components and views -->

  <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
      android:id="@+id/bar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_24"/>

  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/fab"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `FloatingActionButton` can be anchored to the `BottomAppBar` by setting `app:layout_anchor` or by calling `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams#setAnchorId(int)`.

> Note: This things are introduced in Android P versions, you need to
>   have Android studio 3.2 or above.

Checkout this link for detailed explanation :

[Implementing BottomAppBar: Material Components for Android](https://android.jlelse.eu/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-f490c4a01708)