# Android ListView background color masks onClick ripple effect

Tags: java, android, android-listview, background-color

I have a custom `ListView` where each element has an icon and 3 `TextView`s. I am able to change the background to white but now I don't see the dynamic effect when I click on the text. I mean the gray color on touch (ripple effect).

this is the `MainActivity`

```
    ListView mListView = findViewById(R.id.list_layout);

    names = new ArrayList<>();
    macs = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter= new CompleteListAdapter(this, names, macs);

    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Method in my `CompleteListAdapter` which `extends BaseAdapter`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.two_line_icon, parent, false);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    text1.setText(names.get(position));
    text2.setText(macs.get(position));

    return rowView;
}
```

This is part of the `main_activity.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context="com.example.myapp.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"></ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

And this is the single entry of the `ListView`: `two_line_icon.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:foregroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:foregroundTintMode="add"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/img_logo"
    android:tintMode="add"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Texto 1"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Tet2"/>


    <TextView android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="text3"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you talking about Ripple effect?

Comment: @RahulAgrawal yes, thanks for the correct term

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30933094/5444161) it may help you.

Comment: It worked thanks
`android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`